# s3 bucket creates failing and it is working fine in my local system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am going to take snapshot from my local system from s3 bucket, and I am getting below error.

> "error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"repository_exception","reason":"[s3_repository] could not read repository data from index blob"}],"type":"repository_exception","reason":"[s3_repository] could not read repository data from index blob","caused_by":{"type":"i_o_exception","reason":"Exception when listing blobs by prefix [index-]","caused_by":{"type":"amazon_s3_exception","reason":"amazon_s3_exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are using the wrong credentials. Please make sure to use the correct Access Key Id and Secret Access Key for the operation.

Please refer to [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html) if you’re not sure where you can find your AWS credentials.

Comment: but my credentials are working fine in my local system , but this keys are not working in servers

Comment: I think we need a little more context then. Can you please update your question with some information about what you’re trying to do, the environment you’re in, etc.? It is impossible to help based on just an error message.

Comment: i recently updated my aws accesskeys , i deleted my old keys and tried to update my new keys in elasticsearch , after updating my keys it is showing above error message .

Comment: my problem is solved , i am pointing wrong bucket in my commands , when i am taking snapshots from s3 bucket .

Comment: Good to hear that you’ve solved the issue.